# Алгоритм хранения делителей многоугольника

Tags: алгоритм, графика, геометрия, вектор

Есть многоугольник. Пользователь имеет возможность делить его линиями путем добавления двух точек на контур многоугольника. Точки можно ставить как на контур, так и на уже поставленные делители. Таким образом получается многоугольник с внутренней сеткой из делителей. Делители пересекаться не могут.

Знаю один вариант хранения в виде дерева: каждый проем хранит делитель и два проема, на которые делится родительский проем, и так далее. Но такой алгоритм не годится, так как удалить можно только последний введенный делитель, а нужна возможность удалять любой делитель.

Comment: А любой делитель в общем нельзя удалить, если на нем лежит ещё хоть один делитель. Так что так или иначе грохать придется всё поддерево.

Comment: Следует отметить, что в классической связке "алгоритмы + структуры данных" за хранение отвечают всё-таки структуры данных. :) По поводу вопроса: уточните, пожалуйста, почему не походят простейшие структуры данных, скажем, список "сторон или делителей", где каждый новый узел добавляется в конец этого списка и содержит ссылки на "родительские стороны/делители"?

Comment: Vesper, я и говорю, что алгоритм в виде дерева не пойдет.  А по поводу примыканий, то да, если удалить делитель, то примыкающие (те что останутся в воздухе так сказать) должны тоже удалены быть.

Comment: Mark Shevchenko, да тут немного смешано... наверное еще не могу четко сформулировать вопрос... еще ведь кроме структуры нужен алгоритм удаления, изменения данных...

Comment: Mark Shevchenko, список подойдет, наверное. Если с ним не будут какие-то непредвиденные проблемы как с деревом (где при удалении элемента удаляются все дочерние элементы - для пользователя это хаос будет, он не будет понимать почему какие делители остались, а какие-то удалились вместе с выбранным им удаляемым делителем). Дело в том, что потом надо будет: отрисовывать фигуру, перерисовывать, когда будут изменяться/удаляться делители, еще нужны будут субконтуры (на которые многоугольник делится этими делителями)... В общем задач много, чуть ли не векторный редактор сделать.

Comment: Такая вещь по-русски называется «сече́ние» (а не «делитель»), а по-английски — “dissection”.
К сожалению, в литературе описываются в основном сечения многоугольника, построенные на вершинах.

Я правильно понял, что в данной задаче рассекающий многоугольник отрезок может оканчиваться где угодно (либо в вершине, либо где-то на ребре) на периметре?

Comment: Да. Потому что теоретически пользователь может случайно кликнуть мышкой по вершине.

Answer (score 1):

Ключом к описанию сечений ("делителей") является понятие разбиения множеств, при котором каждый элемент является суммой своих разбиений. Сечения следует понимать как структуру разбиений.
С другой стороны, структура описания многоугольника должна совпадать со структурой описания его сечений. Напрашивается описание структуры как дерева, корневым узлом которого является многоугольник.

В соответствии с принципом релевантности, в описание структуры обязаны входить такие параметры.

1. Дочерние элементы - на случай удаления элемента не самого нижнего уровня.
2. Родительский элемент - для корректировки списка дочерних элементов при удалении дочернего элемента.
3. Координаты вершин. Это позволяет решить "на месте" вопрос о сечении точкой, не лежащей на границе родительского сечения.

И отдельного рассмотрения заслуживает вопрос о внутренних пустотах, возникающих при удалении "внучатых" элементов.